# como melhorar o tempo no reconhecimento de voz em python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

Eu estou tentando fazer um programa que escute oque eu digo e responda conforme oque eu falo,mas,quando eu falo ele demora um pouco para reconhecer e responder 
eu tenho um código aqui mais ou menos que eu criei,e eu faço ele abrir uma janela
com o pygame.

Para especificar quando eu executo o código no pycharm ele abre uma janela com uma imagem de fundo e no terminal do pycharm ele escreve estou escutando só que quando eu falo ele demora para reconhecer e responder de volta.

O código:

```
    `import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pygame
pygame.init()

r = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()

x = 1280
y = 720
imagem = pygame.image.load("fundo.jpg")
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
#janela = pygame.display.set_mode((x, y), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
janela = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))

pygame.display.set_caption('I.A')

janela_aberta = True
while janela_aberta == True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            janela_aberta = False

    janela.blit(imagem, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()


    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print ('fale algo: ')
        audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language='pt-br')
            print('você disse: {}'.format(text))
        except:
            print('Desculpe não escutei sua voz')



    #janela.blit(imagem, (0, 0))


    #pygame.draw.line(janela, BLUE, (60, 60), (120, 60), 4)





    #text1 = r.recognize_google(audio, language='pt-br')

    if text == 'sair':
        janela_aberta = False
    elif text == 'Olá':
        engine.say('Ola,como você está')
        engine.runAndWait()
    elif text == 'bem':
        engine.say('então Esta bom!')
        engine.runAndWait()
    #elif text == 'quit':
        b = False
    elif text == "como você está":
        engine.say('como voçe vai?')
        engine.runAndWait()
    elif text == 'Bom dia':
        engine.say("bom dia")
        engine.runAndWait()



    #pygame.draw.line(janela, BLUE, (60, 60), (120, 60), 4)


    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Até onde eu sei, a única forma de diminuir o tempo do reconhecimento é tendo uma ótima qualidade de áudio. Você pode melhorar a qualidade do áudio utilizando o método `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise` que recebe um `source`(no seu caso o microfone) e a duração.

O que esse método faz é ajustar o `Recognizer` para o som do ambiente em que você está. Você pode definir o método para ajustar por 1 segundo e colocar ele antes de fazer a captura do áudio para o recognizer sempre adaptar-se ao ambiente, melhorando o áudio e o reconhecimento.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pygame
pygame.init()

r = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()

x = 1280
y = 720
imagem = pygame.image.load("fundo.jpg")
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
#janela = pygame.display.set_mode((x, y), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
janela = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))

pygame.display.set_caption('I.A')

janela_aberta = True
while janela_aberta == True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            janela_aberta = False

    janela.blit(imagem, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()


    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print ('Fale algo: ')

        # Ajusta o recognizer antes de capturar seu microfone.
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source,duration=1)

        # Captura o som do microfone.
        audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language='pt-br')
            print('você disse: {}'.format(text))
        except:
            print('Desculpe não escutei sua voz')


    #janela.blit(imagem, (0, 0))

    #pygame.draw.line(janela, BLUE, (60, 60), (120, 60), 4)

    #text1 = r.recognize_google(audio, language='pt-br')


    if text == 'sair':
        janela_aberta = False

    elif text == 'Olá':
        engine.say('Ola,como você está')
        engine.runAndWait()

    elif text == 'bem':
        engine.say('então Esta bom!')
        engine.runAndWait()

    #elif text == 'quit':
        b = False

    elif text == "como você está":
        engine.say('como voçe vai?')
        engine.runAndWait()

    elif text == 'Bom dia':
        engine.say("bom dia")
        engine.runAndWait()



    #pygame.draw.line(janela, BLUE, (60, 60), (120, 60), 4)

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: ola obg por me ajudar,aonde eu escreveria 'r.adjust_for_ambient_noise' no meu programa,oque eu teria que modificar,se puder me ajudar agradeço

Comment: Vou colocar seu código modificado na resposta.

Comment: ok muito obg por sua ajuda amigo

Comment: teria como eu baixar a API do speech recognition ou do google

Comment: Como assim baixar a API do speech recognition ? Em relação à API da google, você pode instalar sim e seguir o que manda neste site https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python.  Caso não saiba, a biblioteca speech_recognition já utiliza a API da google quando você chama recognize_google.